# emberjs preserve iframe between route changes

Tags: iframe, ember.js, ember-router

What are the possible ways in which I can preserve an `iframe` embedded in a view in between my route changes?

As the route changes from `Route A-> Route B`, Ember destroys the `View for A`. My `View for A` has an embedded `iframe` which I would love to preserve and not reload when `Route A` is revisited.

So far, I tried moving my `iframe` to a parent view that is not destroyed when exiting `Route A` but browsers reload iframes when you move them around in the DOM, so its a moot exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed nesting is the right choice for you problem of iframe.
[Here is a detailled example](http://jsfiddle.net/Sephy/7hf23wv4/) with a counter to see when the iframe is reloaded.

```
|-home
    |-about
|-elsewhere
```

This important part of the fiddle is :

```
 <div class="border-row">
    This is home
    <iframe src="http://emberjs.com/" width="100%" height="150px" onload="App.HomeController.countLoadings()"></iframe>
     count : {{App.HomeController.loadcount}}<br/>
     isDestroying : {{isDestroying}}<br/>
     isDestroyed : {{isDestroyed}}
</div>
{{outlet}}
```

You can see that the iframe only reloads when you actually move to another part of the hierarchy route. If you navigate between home and about, the iframe stays the same.

Comment: You installed the iframe outside the outlet. In my case, its within Route A or 'about' in your example. I want to preserve it when you navigate out of 'about'.

Comment: You do realize that if it's inside the route and you leave this route, the iframe WILL BE removed from the DOM and if you have the same iframe in another route, the browser will re-insert it into the DOM and reload it ? A hack you could use is to put the iframe as high as possible in your route hierarchy (your application template for instance), and show/hide it with CSS when needed. But this is a hack and certainly not the Ember way.